# Correlation coefficient when Var(X) = 0

Tags: correlation, variance

This is a simple problem I'm sure, but I don't seem to be too good at Stats.  I'm studying for a midterm exam in introductory statistics and found a problem that I can't figure out:
[image]

Since I need the correlation coefficient:

[image]

And the correlation coefficient needs to be between -1 and 1,  neither of the denominator elements can be 0.  But when I tried to solve for Var(X) I got 0 which makes sqrt( Var(X) ) = 0.  I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

I'd write down all the work, but it's a bit of a page full.  I'd really appreciate it if someone could just help me figure out what the correct value of Var(X) is, and how to find it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Two questions. First, what is $\sigma_{xy}$? Also, how do you conclude that $Var(X)$ is 0? If $X$ changes at all, its variance cannot be 0. Based on the definition, it looks that $X$ can take on any value between 0 and $Y$, meaning the variance should be larger than 0.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The σxy is the standard deviation of X*Y.  I've figured that Var(X) can't really be 0, I just can't figure out where the bug in my work is.

Comment: $\sigma_{xy}$ should be the covariance of $x$ and $y$, i.e. $E[(X-E(X))(Y-E[Y])]$.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  Sorry, my mistake.  It is ( σxy = E(X*Y) - E(X)*E(Y) ).  The syntax messed with my brain a bit.

Comment: It should be (1/6)-(1/9)= 3/54= 1/18.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  I'm thoroughly embarrassed.  My bad, I guess I shouldn't stay up late to do these things.

Comment: As we have essentially two answers with the right figure, I think we can safely keep the other one which provides a detailed explanation of how to get 1/18. This why I converted you reply as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ has a marginal triangular distribution $\displaystyle f_x(x)=\int_{y=x}^1 2\,dy = 2-2x$ on $0\lt x \le 1$

so $\displaystyle E[X]=\int_{x=0}^1 x(2-2x)\,dx = \dfrac13$

and  $\displaystyle Var(X)=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=\int_{x=0}^1 x^2(2-2x)\,dx - \dfrac1{3^2}= \dfrac1{18}$

Comment: Haha.  Wow.  I knew it was gonna be something stupid.  A dumb little arithmetic mistake.  Guess I should know better than to stay up late to do this stuff.  Thanks a lot for the help..